# How to escape minus in regular expression with sed?

Tags: sed, filter, expression

I need to free a string from unwanted characters. In this example I want to filter all `+`'s and all `-`'s from **b** and write the result to **c**. So if **b** is `+fdd-dfdf+`, **c** should be `+-+`.

```
read b
c=$(echo $b | sed 's/[^(\+|\-)]//g')
```

But when i run the script, the console says:

> sed: -e expression #1, char 15: Invalid range end

The reason is the `\-` in my regular expression. How can I solve this problem and say, that I want to filter all `-`'s?

Answer (score 6):

are you looking for this?

```
kent$ echo 'a + b + c - d - e'|sed 's/[^-+]//g'
++--
```

Comment: If using bash perhaps `sed 's/[^-+]//g' <<<"a + b + c - d -e" is more succinct.